# Jquery filtering through a multiple range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering, range

Think I'm getting stuck... I'm attempting to take a list of items and create filters based on attributes to the object. I stripped it down into an easier example of books with a cost and year. I currently have a list of books on the page and filters (checkboxes) that can be selected to only show books within a range of cost and/or year. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div id="filters">
<h1>FILTERS</h1>
<div class="filter filter_cost">
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="0" max="9" />Under $10.00<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="10" max="19" />$10-$19<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="20" max="29" />$20-$29<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="30" max="39" />$30-$39<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="40" max="1000" />$40 and Over<br/>
</div>
<div class="filter filter_year">
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="1700" max="1799" />18th Century<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="1800" max="1899" />19th Century<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="1900" max="1999" />20th Century<br/>
    <input class="target" type="checkbox" min="2000" max="2999" />21st Centruy<br/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="books">
<h1>BOOKS</h1>
<div class="book">
    <h1>Book 1</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="cost" value="13" />
    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="1997" />
</div>
<div class="book">
    <h1>Book 2</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="cost" value="22" />
     <input type="hidden" name="year" value="1872" />
</div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery (using 1.6.2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input.target").change(function () {
    filterResults();
});
});

function filterResults(){
$(".book").each(function () {
    var cost = $(this).find("input[name='cost']").val();
    var year = $(this).find("input[name='year']").val();
    var cover = $(this).find("input[name='cover']").val();
    var isHidden = false;
    //console.log("Cost in Range: "+filterRange(cost, ".filter_cost"));
    //console.log("Year in Range: "+filterRange(year, ".filter_year"));

    var filterCost = filterRange(cost, ".filter_cost")?showBook($(this)):hideBook($(this));
    var filterYear = filterRange(year, ".filter_year")?showBook($(this)):hideBook($(this));
    isHidden?"":filterCost;
    isHidden?"":filterYear;

    function showBook(obj) {
        obj.show();
    }

    function hideBook(obj) {
        isHidden = true;
        obj.hide();
    }

})
}

function filterRange(amount, elem) {
var checkedInputs = $(elem).find("input:checked").length;
var totalInputs = $(elem).find("input").length;
var inRange = function(){
    $(elem).find("input:checked").each(function () {
        var min = $(this).attr('min');
        var max = $(this).attr('max');
        if(amount >= min && amount <= max){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
};
if(checkedInputs == 0 || totalInputs == checkedInputs ){
    return true;
} 
if(inRange()){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

My issue is that in the `filterRange` function I'm not sure how to create a range of conditionals based on each input that is checked. So that a price range could be 10-19 and 30-39. My attempt (`var inRange`) was to go through each checked input, check if the cost was with in the range, then return true, else return false. I think I'm just fundamentally getting off track and unsure if this method would work at all. Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the jquery each loop on dom element return statement breaks out of the loop. So your implemenation is wrong. Try this.

```
function filterRange(amount, elem) {
    var checkedInputs = $(elem).find("input:checked").length;
    var totalInputs = $(elem).find("input").length;
    var returnValue = false;

    $(elem).find("input:checked").each(function () {
        var min = $(this).attr('min');
        var max = $(this).attr('max');
        if(amount >= min && amount <= max){
            returnValue = true;
            return true;
        } 
     });

   return (checkedInputs == 0 || totalInputs == checkedInputs || returnValue );
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you... worked great. think i was having a brain stall.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function filterRange(amount, elem) {
    var checkedInputs = $(elem).find("input:checked").length;
    var totalInputs = $(elem).find("input").length;
    var inRange = false;
    $(elem).find("input:checked").each(function () {
        var min = $(this).attr('min');
        var max = $(this).attr('max');
        if (amount >= min && amount <= max) {
            inRange = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (checkedInputs == 0 || totalInputs == checkedInputs) {
        return true;
    }
    if (inRange) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```